# How to detect browser back and refresh button press in JSF 2.0

Tags: jsf-2

I have a JSF page on which i have button inside form. And i am also making a error script.

```
 <ui:composition template="./WEB-INF/templates/layout.xhtml">
     <ui:define name="title">#{newsAndAnnouncementAddUpdate.pageTitle}</ui:define>
     <ui:define name="content">
         <h:form id="news_advertisement_form" prependId="false"  >

             <h:commandButton id="Save"
                              value="#{label.save}"
                              actionListener="#{newsAndAnnouncementAddUpdate.checkForAddUpdate}"
                              disabled="#{newsAndAnnouncementAddUpdate.disable}"
                              styleClass="ButtonStyle"
                              style="position: relative;top: 100px;left: 330px" />

             <h:commandButton id="NoAfterSaveBtn"
                              action="#{newsAndAnnouncementAddUpdate.Cancel}"
                              style="background-color:#e6eff6; border: #e6eff6; visibility:hidden">
             </h:commandButton>
             <h:outputText value="#{newsAndAnnouncementAddUpdate.errorScript}" escape="false"/>

        </h:form>

        <h:commandButton id="YesAfterSaveBtn"
                         action="#{newsAndAnnouncementAddUpdate.stayOnpage}"
                         style="background-color:#e6eff6; border:#e6eff6; visibility:hidden">
        </h:commandButton>

    </ui:define>

</ui:composition>
```

My error script is generating like this

```
@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class NewsAndAnnouncementAddUpdate implements Serializable {

    private String errorScript;
    private String field;

    //Constructor
    public NewsAndAnnouncementAddUpdate() {
         errorScript = "";
         ...
    } //end of constructor

    public String getErrorScript() {
        return errorScript;
    }

    public void setErrorScript(String errorScript) {
        this.errorScript = errorScript;
    }

}//end of class NewsAndAnnouncementAddUpdate
```

When user click on save button, then the following method called and put something in the errorScript variable. When first time page loads then nothing in the errorScript variable so nothing happens. But when user click on save button, then i check whether any required field is empty, and if yes then i generate the error script like the following

```
public void checkForAddUpdate(ActionEvent event) {

    String result = validations();
    System.out.println(errorScript);
    if (result.equals("OK")) {
        System.out.println("Every Thinsg is fine");
    } else if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("error")) {
        return;
    }
    ...
} //end of checkForAddUpdate()

private String validations() {
    if (headline.trim().equals("")) {
        makeErrorScript("headline");          
        return "error";
    } else if (details.trim().equals("")) {
        ...
    } else {
        return "OK";
    }
} //end of validations()

private void makeErrorScript(String field){

    field = ConnectionUtil.getMessage("labels", field, null);
    String[] replace = {field};
    String message = ConnectionUtil.getMessage("messages_en_US", "emptyfield", replace);
    errorScript = ConnectionUtil.getErrorMessages(message);

} //end of makeErrorScript()
```

I simply make message. like **Headline must be entered** and pass this as a parameter to getErrroMessage. Here is my method

```
public static String getErrorMessages(String errorParam) {

   errorParam = "\""+ errorParam + "\"";
   String myScript = "<script>"
           + "           $(document).ready(function(){"
           + "               $.dialog({ "
           + "                   message: " + errorParam +","
           + "                   imageIcon: false          ,"
           + "                   type: \"error\"           ,"
           + "                   okButtonID: \"ok\"        , "
           + "                   okButtonValue: \"OK\""
           + "               });"  //end of $.dialog()
           + "           });" //end of $(document).ready(fn)
           + "       </script>";

    return myScript;

} //end of getErrorMessages()
```

Now you can see that when first time user opens the page, the errorScript variable is empty, so nothing is shown, But when you click on save button, if required field is missing, then i generate the error script, this script is placed inside the errorScript variable, which replaces the **h:outputText value="#{newsAndAnnouncementAddUpdate.errorScript}" escape="false"** and run the script, and the dialog is shown. everything is working fine up to now.

But i just noticed that once a dialog is shown, and then you press the refresh button, then instead of calling constructor(You are refreshing the page , so the page should be load from scratch) it calls my **checkForAddUpdate(ActionEvent event)**. Here errorScript is not empty, so it again shows the message. Logically when i refresh the page then constructor should be call, in constructor i am using errorSript=""; so no message will be shown on page refresh. Why it is calling **checkForAddUpdate(ActionEvent event)** when i do page refresh? I want that when user press the refresh button, then my errorScript variable should become **empth("")**, so dialog do not show. Is there any way i can detect the browser refresh button press and then empty the errorScript variable. I have many input type. or select type variables, i am not handling with just one required attribute.

Actually i was not figuring out that on save button click how can i pass this message to my script like, Headline must be entered. Because i am getting messges from the JSF resource file. If i hard coded the values for jQuery(JavaScript), then my localization effected. That's why i am doing on this manner.

But i want to ask am i doing it in right way? Or there is better approach that i can use for generating errorScript. I have to use this dialog. Means my script should be invoke.

Thanks

Comment: why don't u try generating the error messages using h:message tags

Comment: I have to use this script. Actually when this script runs then the message dialog shown. I gave suggestions to my seniors, but they said this message dialog is approved by the client. Do you mean to say... generate the script using h:message tag... Is it?

Comment: I might be missing something as I know little of JSF2, but why is your NewsAndAnnouncementAddUpdate view-scoped instead of request-scoped?
As long as you don't change the page (i.e. view), and refresh isn't changing the page, the same bean instance will be used, and thus the errorScript will persist across refreshes.